# Paypal API: Get balance of other users?

Tags: python, api, paypal

Let's say people put a "Paypal donate" button on my website. Is it possible for me to get their current balance through the API (with their permission, of course) ? Or how can the owner display its balance on my website?

If this is possible, then which Python library should I use for Paypal?

Comment: I do not know exactly which api to call , you can refer x.com ( Paypal developer network )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the balance issue, but could that projet be a start to see which features are available ?

https://github.com/patcoll/paypal-python

That document

http://www.scribd.com/doc/30661771/Web2py-Paypal-Integration

mentions a balance option : "Session . balance is a value with the total of the transacion "

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

tested, works & returns a string.
    https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_GetBalance_php.txt